# How can the binary program installed on the client server be conveniently authorized on the authorization server (it has a validity period)?

Tags: linux, server, authorization, ip

**the goal:**

1. The customer cannot make the program available on other ips by copying.
2. It is best not to write special authorization information (such as token) into the program. I need to compile separately because of different clients.
3. Only need the customer to fill in simple information to complete the authorization. For example, the server ip address.

**The way I think** about implementation is that the authorization server resolves the accessed IP, and if the IP is in the authorization list, the authorization is successful.

**The question:**

1. What are the loopholes in my current thinking?
2. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is enough

make sure client cannot crack your program

Comment: I have considered this. Attacked, I can just change the server. My code is very simple, just copy it directly.